# Convertir xlsx o csv a un 'nested' JSON en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, excel, csv, jsonobject

Tengo la siguiente tabla excel o csv:

```
Lugar  | Salon
Lugar1 | Salon1
Lugar1 | Salon2
Lugar2 | Salon3
Lugar2 | Salon4
```

y la quiero pasar a este JSON:

```
{
   "nombre": "Lugar1",
   "salones": [
              {"nombre": "Salon1"},
              {"nombre": "Salon2"}
           ]
},
{
   "nombre": "Lugar2",
   "salones": [
              {"nombre": "Salon3"},
              {"nombre": "Salon4"}
           ]
}
```

Tienen idea de la forma más simple de hacerlo? No encontré forma de hacerlo con la librería SheetJS js-xlsx, que sólo me sirvió para JSON planos, y tampoco encontré otra que lo hiciera.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los datos de tu archivo csv, recorrerlo linea por linea. En tu logica de Node Js, haces un split por el caracter pipe '|' y del arreglo que obtengas formas un objecto JSON recorriendo cada uno de estos datos.